# jython: port definition

Tags: websphere, jython

I am looking for a  jython script that does the following:

1. Servers > application servers > server1 > Ports > WC_default > (set) port=8080.
2. enviornment > virtaul hosts > deault_host > host aliases > [if there is an entry with host name==*, then port = 8080]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code as a starting point:

```
serverEntries = AdminConfig.list('ServerEntry', AdminConfig.getid('/Node:' + nodeName + '/')).split(java.lang.System.getProperty('line.separator'))
for serverEntry in serverEntries:
    if AdminConfig.showAttribute(serverEntry, "serverName") == 'server1':
        sepString = AdminConfig.showAttribute(serverEntry, "specialEndpoints")
        sepList = sepString[1:len(sepString)-1].split(" ")
        for specialEndPoint in sepList:
            endPointNm = AdminConfig.showAttribute(specialEndPoint, "endPointName")
            if endPointNm == "WC_defaulthost":
                ePoint = AdminConfig.showAttribute(specialEndPoint, "endPoint")
                # at this point you probably want to do a resetAttribute instead of showAttribute
                defaultHostPort = AdminConfig.showAttribute(ePoint, "port")
                break

for hostAlias in AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:' + cellName + '/VirtualHost:default_host/HostAlias:/').split(java.lang.System.getProperty('line.separator')):
    if AdminConfig.showAttribute(hostAlias, 'port') == defaultHostPort:
        print "Deleting host alias for port " + defaultHostPort
        AdminConfig.remove(hostAlias)
AdminConfig.create('HostAlias', AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:' + cellName + '/VirtualHost:default_host/'), [['hostname', '*'],['port', defaultHostPort]])
```